# React -router doesn't add component to the dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have  `Quotes` component which  contains  list of quotes. When I click individual list element, react router changes the  url dynamically and opens it in full page which is `Full_Screen_Quotes` then again  inside the `Full_Screen_Quotes` I want to  add    `Comments` section on button click with the help of react router, but it  does not work for the reason I do not know. What might be the reason?

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min"
import Comments from "./Comments"
import classes from '../css/Full_Screen_Quote.module.css'
import db from "./db"
import { useState } from "react"
import { Router,Route } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min"
 const Full_Screen_Quotes = ()=>{
     const params =  useParams()
     return(

       <>   
<div  className={classes.quote}>
   <h1>{params.quoteId} </h1>
   <h4>{params.authorId}</h4>
   <Link to = {`/Allquotes/${params.authorId}/${params.quoteId}/comments`}>  // Link that adds comment section
     <button>ADD</button>
   </Link>
</div>   
 
 <Route path ={`/Allquotes/${params.authorId}/${params.quoteId}/comments` }  exact > //Comment section path
  <Comments></Comments>
  </Route>  
       </>
     )
 }
 export default Full_Screen_Quotes
```

> App js

```
   
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Link} from'react-router-dom'
import MainHeader from '../src/components/MainHeader'
import Quotes from '../src/components/Quotes'
import AddQuotes from './components/AddQuotes';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import ListElement from './components/ListElement';
import Full_Screen_Quote from '../src/components/Full_Screen_Quote'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from '../src/components/Home'
import NotFound from './NotFound';
import {useState,useCallback,useMemo} from 'react'
import { Prompt } from 'react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min'
import Comments from './components/Comments';



function App() {
 
  const [is_focused,set_is_focused] = useState(false)
 
  return (
    <div> 
<Switch>
 <Route path ='/Welcome/'  exact>   
  <Welcome/>
 </Route>
 
 <Route path ='/Allquotes/' exact>    
   <Quotes   />
 </Route>
 
 <Route path ='/Addquote/' exact>
   <AddQuotes  set_is_focused = {set_is_focused} is_focused={is_focused} />
 </Route>
 
 <Route path ='/Allquotes/:authorId/:quoteId' exact>
  <Full_Screen_Quote />
 </Route>   

</Switch>
 
   </div>
   
  )
}

export default App;
```

> Comments js

```
 import { useState } from "react"
 import db from '../components/db'
 import { useRef } from "react"
  const Comments = (props)=>{
       return (
        <div style={{display:'flex',justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <div> <textarea  style={{transition:'1s all'}}></textarea> </div>
       </div>
     )}
 export default Comments
```

Answer (score 1):

Your root router/`Switch` is ***exactly*** matching URL paths, and in the case of rendering the `Full_Screen_Quote` component it only ***exactly*** matches ***up to*** `'/Allquotes/:authorId/:quoteId'`

```
<Route path ='/Allquotes/:authorId/:quoteId' exact>
  <Full_Screen_Quote />
</Route>
```

As soon as the path becomes "/Allquotes/someAuthorId/someQuoteId}/comments" it no longer matches exactly and your `Full_Screen_Quote` component is unmounted, thus unmounting the nested `Route` you want to render for the `Comments` component.

In 99.99% for use cases there's really no need to use the `exact` prop in conjunction with the `Switch` since you can order the rendered routes in inverse order of path specificity so matching can work properly. Using the `exact` prop also necessarily precludes the further matching of any nested routes.

You've a couple options:

1. Order the routes in the `Switch` in descending path specificity order and remove the `exact` prop. This allows the nested route in `Full_Screen_Quote` to be eventually matched and rendered.

   ```
   <Switch>
     <Route path='/Welcome/'>   
       <Welcome />
     </Route>
     <Route path='/Allquotes/:authorId/:quoteId'>
       <Full_Screen_Quote />
     </Route>
     <Route path='/Allquotes/'>    
       <Quotes />
     </Route>
     <Route path='/Addquote/'>
       <AddQuotes
         set_is_focused={set_is_focused}
         is_focused={is_focused}
       />
     </Route>
   </Switch>
   ```

   ...

   ```
   const Full_Screen_Quotes = () => {
     const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
     const params = useParams();
     return (
       <>
         <div className={classes.quote}>
           <h1>{params.quoteId} </h1>
           <h4>{params.authorId}</h4>
           <Link to={`/${url}/comments`}> 
             <button>ADD</button>
           </Link>
         </div>
         <Route path={`${path}/comments`}>
           <Comments />
         </Route> 
       </> 
     );
   };
   ```
2. Move the nested route out to the main router/`Switch` and order the routes in descending path specificity order and remove the `exact` prop.

   ```
   <Switch>
     <Route path='/Welcome/'>   
       <Welcome />
     </Route>
     <Route path='/Allquotes/:authorId/:quoteId/comments'>
       <Comments />
     </Route> 
     <Route path='/Allquotes/:authorId/:quoteId'>
       <Full_Screen_Quote />
     </Route>
     <Route path='/Allquotes/'>    
       <Quotes />
     </Route>
     <Route path='/Addquote/'>
       <AddQuotes
         set_is_focused={set_is_focused}
         is_focused={is_focused}
       />
     </Route>
   </Switch>
   ```

   ...

   ```
   const Full_Screen_Quotes = () => {
     const { url } = useRouteMatch();
     const params = useParams();

     return (
       <div className={classes.quote}>
         <h1>{params.quoteId} </h1>
         <h4>{params.authorId}</h4>
         <Link to={`/${url}/comments`}> 
           <button>ADD</button>
         </Link>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the app.js in a router

`import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'`

then

```
 <Router> 
<Switch>
 <Route path ='/Welcome/'  exact>   
  <Welcome/>
 </Route>
 
 <Route path ='/Allquotes/' exact>    
   <Quotes   />
 </Route>
 
 <Route path ='/Addquote/' exact>
   <AddQuotes  set_is_focused = {set_is_focused} is_focused={is_focused} />
 </Route>
 
 <Route path ='/Allquotes/:authorId/:quoteId' exact>
  <Full_Screen_Quote />
 </Route>   

</Switch>
 
   </Router>
```

Comment: now it gives props.history is undefined error